# Can I use monad transformers to simplify this composition?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, monad-transformers, kleisli

suppose I have

```
type VS[A] = Validation[String, A]

val v: VS[Option[A]]
val f: A => VS[B]
```

I want to get a result of type `VS[Option[B]]` but if `v` is a `Success(None)`, the result should also be a `Success(None)`. Here's an example:

```
scala> val v: VS[Option[String]] = some("4.5").success
v: VS[Option[String]] = Success(Some(4.5))

scala> val f = (s : String) => (try { s.toInt.success } catch { case x => x.getMessage.fail }): VS[Int]
f: String => VS[Int] = <function1>
```

Then:

```
scala> import Validation.Monad._
import Validation.Monad._

scala> (v map2 f map (_.sequence)).join
res4: scalaz.Validation[String,Option[Int]] = Failure(For input string: "4.5")
```

The success case is:

```
scala> val v: VS[Option[String]]= some("5").success
v: VS[Option[String]] = Success(Some(5))

scala> (v map2 f map (_.sequence)).join //UGLY composition
res7: scalaz.Validation[String,Option[Int]] = Success(Some(5))
```

And the empty case is:

```
scala> val v: VS[Option[String]]= none[String].success
v: VS[Option[String]] = Success(None)

scala> (v map2 f map (_.sequence)).join
res6: scalaz.Validation[String,Option[Int]] = Success(None)
```

Is there a "nicer" way of doing this (possibly involving kleisli composition or monad transformers)?

Answer (score 5):

The monad transformer `OptionT` does exactly what you want here, and its `flatMapF` method makes usage a clean one-liner.

I'm going to use Scalaz 7's disjunction type (`\/`) instead of `Validation` in this example, since the latter isn't a monad in Scalaz 7, but the principle is the same.

```
import scalaz._, std.option._, syntax.id._, syntax.monad._

type DS[+A] = String \/ A
type ODS[A] = OptionT[DS, A]

def f(s: String) = try s.toInt.right catch { case e => e.getMessage.left }
```

Now we can write the following:

```
scala> val v = OptionT(some("4.5").point[DS])
v: scalaz.OptionT[DS,java.lang.String] = OptionT(\/-(Some(4.5)))

scala> (v flatMapF f).run
res0: DS[Option[Int]] = -\/(For input string: "4.5")
```

Or equivalently:

```
scala> ("4.5".point[ODS] flatMapF f).run
res1: DS[Option[Int]] = -\/(For input string: "4.5")
```

Or the success case:

```
scala> ("4".point[ODS] flatMapF f).run
res2: DS[Option[Int]] = \/-(Some(4))
```

Or the empty case:

```
scala> (OptionT(none.point[DS]) flatMapF f).run
res3: DS[Option[Int]] = \/-(None)
```

As desired.